# How to validate semver for x range

Tags: npm

I am trying to validate wildcard/xrange semver version spec using npm module https://www.npmjs.com/package/semver .

This is what I tried (`1.x.x/1.*.*` is user input) .

```
const semver = require('semver')
console.log(semver.satisfies("*","1.x.x"))
console.log(semver.gt("1.x.x", "0.0.0"))
```

But this is not working

Comment: The `npm` tag should get you help with all things NPM. The `semmantic-versioning` tag is for [SemVer spec](https://semver/) related questions.

Answer (score 0):

The first argument of `semver.satisfies` and both arguments of `semver.gt` should be specific versions like `1.2.3`, not version ranges.

---

Maybe `semver.minVersion(range)` or `subset(subRange, superRange)` is what you want. You can check more details at https://github.com/npm/node-semver.